Why module pyecharts can't be found
I create a virtual environment with pycharts (see the answer to this question)
The virtual environment is created.
But When I tried to run the code
import streamlit as st
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Scatter, Line
from pyecharts.faker import Faker
from pyecharts.render import make_snapshot
from snapshot_phantomjs import snapshot


def main():
    st.title("Echarts Point Example with Streamlit")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

with streamlit run myfile.py , the module snapshot-phantomjs could not be found. therefore I added it. Because it is not in the nix package managers, I build it with buildPythongPackage
{
description = "";

  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";


outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python = pkgs.python311;

        
    snapshot-phantomjs = with pkgs.python3Packages;
      buildPythonPackage rec {
        pname = "snapshot-phantomjs";
        version = "0.0.3";

        src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
          inherit pname version;
          sha256 = "3c94bc4b81147e4b44b3f745e3fbe52db4536729cdd464cbfdd2edbfb0789947";
        };
        propagatedBuildInputs = [ pip pep517 nose pyecharts ];


    };
    
    pyecharts = with pkgs.python3Packages;
      buildPythonPackage rec {
        pname = "pyecharts";
        version = "2.0.6";

        src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
          inherit pname version;
          sha256 = "4d7f8dcbee1525a6eeecab589efcdbe939feee4c46930d90b2734bff04077ecc";
        };
        propagatedBuildInputs = [ simplejson prettytable jinja2 ];

    };

    python_packages = python.withPackages(ps: with ps;[
      ipython
      pyecharts
      snapshot-phantomjs
      streamlit 

    ]);

    myDevTools = [
      python_packages
    ];
  in {
    devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
      buildInputs = myDevTools;          
    };
  });

}
nix develop works but when I try to run my code again (streamlit run myfile.py), I get this error
File "/mnt/c/Users/Pierre-Olivier/Documents/doc/echart_test/withStreamlit/a.py", line 2, in 
from pyecharts import options as opts
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyecharts'
